# Determine signal in receiver

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I need to create Redirect object when page with certain attribute gets either removed or set disabled, so what it's saved I need to determine if it's disabled, or if it's deleted I need to create this Redirect anyway.

```
@receiver([post_save, pre_delete], sender=MyModel, dispatch_uid='seo.models.add_redirect')
def add_redirect(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.option and (instance.enabled == False or signal == pre_delete):
        Redirect.objects.create(site_id=1, from_url=instance.get_absolute_url()[1:],
                                    to_url=instance.category.get_absolute_url())
```

So how can I figure out which signal is emitted inside the handler?

Comment: In `post_save` there will be a key named `created` which will not be there in `delete`

Comment: Why not create 2 different handlers?